# csr_matrix indptr purpose?

Tags: python, scipy

I am wondering about the purposes of indptr over the standard row, col definition. Is it preferable to use indptr because the list stores less bits of data? If this is the case, why not always use this method (assuming the row, col list is ordered)?

Comment: The 'c' in `csr` stands for 'condensed'.  Usually (but not always) this use of `indptr` requires a shorter array than the `coo` style `rows`.  `indptr` has one value per row (plus 1).  Also most of the calculation methods, especially matrix multiplication, have developed using this `csr` format.  It's use goes back quite a ways, before Python.  But the `coo` style of inputs is usually easier for users to understand and use.

Comment: The format is well known outside of Python: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format).  As far as I know, `csc` is the only format used in MATLAB, though users can provide a `coo` style inputs.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. This makes sense though I don't think it is as intuitive or flexible as the rows and cols version.

Comment: Usually you don't have to deal with `indptr` directly.  While you can create an `csr` matrix with those arrays, but you can just as easily create it with the `coo` style (the `coo` to `csr` conversion is relatively fast).  I only use `indptr` if I'm doing some custom row by row iteration.  `lil` is a more intuitive way of looking at the matrix row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Heres some info i found out about `indptr` and `csr_matrix` on [SciPy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html)

```
csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)])
```

- Is the standard CSR representation where the column indices for row `i` are stored in `indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]` and their corresponding values are stored in `data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]`. If the shape parameter is not supplied, the matrix dimensions are inferred from the index arrays.
- **indptr** - CSR format index pointer array of the matrix

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but I have already looked at the documentation and it doesn't answer my question. I am wondering why is it used not how.